# Не работает класс прописаный к элементу

Tags: css

есть класс который добавляется к активным элементам формы и при `hover` у них появляется рамка, но на деле рамки почему то нет. если через хром смотреть на код то рамка на ховере зачеркнута (скрин) в css от код класса прописан в самом низу

[image: link text]

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у тебя граница прописана в атрибуте style.

Answer (score 0):

зачеркнутые - это означает, что стиль перекрывается верхним. Попробуй к своим стилям дописать !important;

Comment: Вредный ответ. Просто не надо в style напрямую прописывать стили.